# Help with amplifying voice on a call recording

Tags: audio-recording, noise

I recorded a market research interview using ACR recorder on my andriod. I can hardly hear the person on other side when I play the recording. Tried amplifying through Audacity, using compressor settings and even noise reduction but nothing worked. Is there any other solution? Please help

Comment: I don't understand if this is a volume question or a sound clarity / EQ question. Downvote until the question becomes clear.

Comment: Also stating that you already used a compressor doesn't mean nothing if you don't write down the settings and the results u got.

Comment: Please accept my apologies for the confusion. It is actually a mix of both. I am unable to hear the volume of person on the other side and when I try to use the compressor settings in Audacity there is a lot of background noise. In other words if I amplify along with volume even the noise increases. Compressor settings is used are Threshold: -60db, Noise floor: -80 db, Ratio: 5:1, Attack Time: 0.10 secs and Release time: 1.0 secs. I am new to the forum and not sure how can I share the clip. I will be glad to share a small clip if you can please guide how to do so.

Comment: You'll have to edit your question , you can embed a soundcloud or any other website that provides that kind of service. It'll be good to edit your question providing some details you don't have to be that explicit but on the other hand it's better to be very explicit than to not be explicit at all.

Comment: Thanks a ton for guidance. I'll update the question with details.

Answer (score 0):

You amplified and compressed but "nothing worked". What does that mean? I would think that not working means it doesn't increase the volume. But you say it increases the noise with the voice, which means it's working exactly how it's supposed to.

When you compress, you are reducing the amplitude of the signal above the threshold by the ratio. So, if you are putting the threshold at -80dB as you say, you would be smashing everything starting at that level (which would include the noise), then when you boost all of that, you are increasing the noise (which is now much closer in level to the voice). You need to try increasing your threshold quite a bit. It might be better to not compress at all, and just boost the whole thing.

You can also try EQ, especially with a high-pass filter. Without the wav, it's hard to give suggestions.

Comment: Hello AvtAyt thank you for the update. Please see below the link where I have uploaded part of a call. First few seconds is my voice which is very clear however can't hear anything. Due to confidentiality of project I can't upload the entire call. I hope this helps. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqP4sRD0iZyriaUEG2UkAXIw6NVT3w

Comment: That's fine, that chunk is enough. Sadly, there's not much i can think of to fix that. The second voice is right by the sound floor, so about all you can do is boost and ignore the (horrendous) noise that will definitely be there with it. There may be someone who'll come by and give an answer with something i haven't heard of though.